# I'm trying to make a new directory in PuTTY, but the error is coming that the permission is denied

Tags: server

Command sequence:

```
atlas:/> cd etc
atlas:/etc> mkdir dir1
mkdir: cannot create directory `dir1': Permission denied
atlas:/etc> mkdir dir1
mkdir: cannot create directory `dir1': Permission denied
atlas:/etc> mkdir dir1.
mkdir: cannot create directory `dir1.': Permission denied
atlas:/etc>
```

How can I get out from this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To create a folder in `/etc`, you must use root permissions. Use this instead:

```bsh
sudo mkdir dir1
```

If you need access to that afterwards, you will always have to use `sudo`, or you will have to change permissions of the folder or files within.